# Integrating a ChangeNotifier with a FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, provider

I know the subject of updating information from a FutureProvider has come up on here so I want to avoid repeating prior discussion.  I found a really useful way to integrate FutureProvider into my app to pull in information from Firebase's Real-Time Database (as opposed to having to reuse the same async functions on 4 or 5 different screens).  In further testing, of course, I came to realize that any changes to the Real-Time Database do not take effect in the FutureProvider until I restart the app, even if I toggle listen to true or directly call my fetchUser() method in my FutureProvider.

I ask if anyone has had success merging a ChangeNotifier with a FutureProvider to notify listeners of an update?  I've tried a few approaches and have not had success.  Here is my latest:

**My main.dart:**

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:fast_food_health_e/widgets/nutritionixList.dart';
SharedPreferences preferences;


void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(FastFoodHealthEApp());
   }
 class FastFoodHealthEApp extends StatelessWidget {
 final FirebaseServices firebaseServices = FirebaseServices();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [

    Provider<AuthenticationProvider>(
    create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider(FirebaseAuth.instance),
     ),
     StreamProvider(
     create: (context) => context.read<AuthenticationProvider>().authState,
     ),
     ChangeNotifierProvider(
     create: (context) => FirebaseServices(),
    child: (
    FutureProvider(create: (context) => firebaseServices.fetchUser(),
     catchError: (context, error) {
     print("The Error is: " + error.toString());
    },)

    ),
    ),
   ],

  child: MaterialApp(

    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
```

**My FutureProvider:**

```
 class FirebaseServices with ChangeNotifier{



   Future<FastFoodHealthEUser> fetchUser()
  async{
    // var firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
    // String userID  = firebaseUser.uid;
    Map<String, dynamic> theMap;
   final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
   final User user = auth.currentUser;
   final uid = user.uid;

   notifyListeners();

    final referenceDatabase = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child(uid)
        .once()
        .then((snapshot){theMap = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);});





    return FastFoodHealthEUser.fromJson(theMap);



  }
```

**Class with an invocation of the FutureProvider:**

```
 @override
   void didChangeDependencies() {


setUpUsers();



super.didChangeDependencies();
```

}

```
void setUpUsers () async  {



firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
userID  = firebaseUser.uid;
fastFoodHealthEUser =  Provider.of<FastFoodHealthEUser>(context, listen: true);


this._getMoreData();


}



void _getMoreData() async {




if(fastFoodHealthEUser!=null){




    Calories = fastFoodHealthEUser.todaysCal;

    print("Just testing this: " + Calories.toString());

    sodium = fastFoodHealthEUser.todaysSodium;
```

Probably unsurprisingly, I get an error about not being able to find the correct Provider doing it as above:

*E/flutter ( 3492): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MyDiaryScreen Widget*

Am I foolish for trying this with a FutureProvider?  Might a StreamProvider be better?  I just find FutureProvider more useful (as before my screens were chalk full of FutureBuilders, but I never had an issue updating them with new data).

Comment: Just to update my own quandry, I followed this example heavily and managed to get the combination of a ChangeNotifierProvider calling out to Firebase (in my case I adapted it for the Firebase Realtime Database as opposed to Firestore) working properly and update my app when I make changes to the data within the app.  If anyone runs into a similar issue I would love to help.  [YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iu9DpbzR83s)